# Extracting a clip from a video with low fps

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to extract a clip from a video( downloaded from [1]) (which has low frame rate) by specifying the start and end time. In order to do that, I use the following command:

**ffmpeg -i example.webm -ss 116.38 -to 126.38 clip.mpg**

however, I get the following error:

---

```
ffmpeg version N-80026-g936751b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
libavutil 55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
libavcodec 57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
libavformat 57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
libavdevice 57. 0.101 / 57. 0.101
libavfilter 6. 45.100 / 6. 45.100
libavresample 3. 0. 0 / 3. 0. 0
libswscale 4. 1.100 / 4. 1.100
libswresample 2. 0.101 / 2. 0.101
libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'example.webm':
Metadata:
encoder : Google
Duration: 00:04:22.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 207 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 630x360, SAR 1:1 DAR 7:4, 6 fps, 6 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[mpeg1video @ 0x252f200] MPEG1/2 does not support 5/1 fps
Output #0, mpeg, to 'clip.mpg':
Metadata:
encoder : Google
Stream #0:0: Unknown: none, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0 (default)
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc57.42.100 mpeg1video
Stream #0:1: Unknown: none (default)
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc57.42.100 mp2
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (vorbis (native) -> mp2 (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I tried by adding -r 20 to the above command. It works in this case but not sure this is correct way to do it.
I was wondering how can I extract the clip from this video given start time and endtime? what are parameters should I use? or what is correct way to do it?

Thanks.

[1]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc52pGHr0xc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it to WebM or MP4

WebM:

```
ffmpeg -i example.webm -ss 116.38 -to 126.38 -c copy clip.webm
```

MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i example.webm -ss 116.38 -to 126.38 clip.mp4
```

As the error message says, your command converts the video to MPEG-1 (a 30-year old codec) which does not support 5 fps, the framerate of your source.